# ActiveRecord enum error: "is not a valid value"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, enums

I have a model with enum:

```
  enum pending_users: {
    pending_users_disabled: 0,
    pending_users_enabled: 1
  }
```

And here is how the field described in schema.rb:

```
t.integer  "pending_users",             limit: 4,     default: 0, null: false
```

When I try to update it via the controller with the following parameters:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "group"=>{"pending_users"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Update Group", "id"=>"33"}
```

I see the following error:

```
ArgumentError - '1' is not a valid pending_users:
  activerecord (4.2.7.1) lib/active_record/enum.rb:104:in `block (3 levels) in enum'
  activerecord (4.2.7.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `_assign_attribute'
  activerecord (4.2.7.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:41:in `block in assign_attributes'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:185:in `each_pair'
  activerecord (4.2.7.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `assign_attributes'
  activerecord (4.2.7.1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:251:in `block in update'
  activerecord (4.2.7.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.2.7.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.7.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.7.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.7.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.7.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.2.7.1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:250:in `update'
  app/controllers/groups_controller.rb:53:in `update'
```

From my perspective, 1 is a valid value for the enum. What can cause such behavior?

Comment: You should really just use `enum pending_users: %w(enabled disabled)`. The `pending_users_` prefix is redundant.

Comment: @meagar I didn't include the whole model here. In fact I have other enabled/disabled enums in my model and there is no way in rails 4 to include several different enums with the same value, unfortunately

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should assign the enum with a string (the key). So `1` should instead be `"pending_users_enabled"`.